# D3js from this example, how data is passedd to the other function in another file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this Box-Plot [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502), I'm curious to know how data is passed from `index.html` into below function `box(g)` in `box.js`. I have background in Python, Java and R where data/parameters will be passed to another method by it being called and passed those values. This should be the same as JavaScript function but I don't see that here. So, I'm looking for the explanation.

```
(function() {

// Inspired by http://informationandvisualization.de/blog/box-plot
d3.box = function() {
  var width = 1,
      height = 1,
      duration = 0,
      domain = null,
      value = Number,
      whiskers = boxWhiskers,
      quartiles = boxQuartiles,
      tickFormat = null;

  // For each small multiple…
  function box(g) {
    g.each(function(d, i) {
```

Thank you in advance.